# When i added mapping object in dynamo Db, Why it's order will change automatically?

Tags: mapping, amazon-dynamodb

```
Record1: [{
    "business_id": 2,
    "form_id": 1,
    "forms": {
        "v2": {
            "id": "f522",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 1"
        },
        "v3": {
            "id": "f8b6",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 2"
        },
        "v1": {
            "id": "fw56",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 3"
        },
        "v5": {
            "id": "fw56",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 3"
        },
        "v4": {
            "id": "fw56",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 3"
        }
    }
}]
```

I am going to add above record in dynamo Db table. I am going to add mapping in the form object. I have added mapping value in following order v2,v3,v1,v5,v4. But it is stored in dynamo DB like following order v1,v2,v3,v4,v5. 
I don't want to change mapping order. Please suggest.

Comment: I am going to add above record in dynamo Db table. I am going to add mapping in form object. I have added mapping value in following order v2,v3,v1,v5,v4. But it is stored in dynamo DB like following order v1,v2,v3,v4,v5. I don't want to change mapping order. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `forms` attribute has `Map` type, which doesn't preserve order of items.

From [DynamoDB docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes.Document.Map):

> A map type attribute can store an unordered collection of name-value
>   pairs.

To preserve the order of child items in `forms` container in your case, I would convert the attribute into a [`List`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes.Document.List), like this:

```
Record1: {
    "business_id": 2,
    "form_id": 1,
    "forms": [
      {"formKey": "v2", "id": "f522", "is_deleted": 0, "title": "Form 1"},
      {"formKey": "v3", "id": "f8b6", "is_deleted": 0, "title": "Form 2"}, 
      {"formKey": "v1", "id": "fw56", "is_deleted": 0, "title": "Form 3"},
      {"formKey": "v5", "id": "fw56", "is_deleted": 0, "title": "Form 3"},
      {"formKey": "v4", "id": "fw56", "is_deleted": 0, "title": "Form 3"}    
    ]
}
```